# mapping and filtering chaining

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The data looks like this

```
[{time: '09:00', 'level':'x3', 'type':'ae'}
time: '10:00', 'level':'x6', 'type':'fe'}
time: '09:00', 'level':'y3', 'type':'hy'}
time: '11:00', 'level':'z3', 'type':'hy'}]
```

The result what i would like to get:
filter by the time - 09:00, and create splitted arrays for the same kinds.

Example result:

```
{"levels": [ "x3","y3"],"types": ["ae","hy"]}
```

I can do this in three function(filter and map) but I would like to chain them. Is it possible in more elegant way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you doing it now?

Comment: @A.Lau, filter, map and map again.

Comment: the expected result is not possible, because it has two properties with the same name.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid!

Comment: @NinaScholz that's not the only problem, OP is also trying to put object terminology inside an array container

Comment: That was figurative but i changed as ibrahim' answer

Comment: Wasn't your question: "map and filter chaining"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** the result will be an object containing the two arrays. To get that object, you can use `reduce` like this:

```js
var arr = [
  {time: '09:00', 'level':'x3', 'type':'ae'},
  {time: '10:00', 'level':'x6', 'type':'fe'},
  {time: '09:00', 'level':'y3', 'type':'hy'},
  {time: '11:00', 'level':'z3', 'type':'hy'}
];

var result = arr.filter(o => o.time === '09:00')
                .reduce((acc, o) => {
                    acc.levels.push(o.level);
                    acc.types.push(o.type);
                    return acc;
                }, {levels: [], types: []});
   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter and map the properties you want and get an object with wanted properties and all values in an array.

```js
var array = [{time: '09:00', 'level':'x3', 'type':'ae'}, {time: '10:00', 'level':'x6', 'type':'fe'},{time: '09:00', 'level':'y3', 'type':'hy'},{time: '11:00', 'level':'z3', 'type':'hy'}],
    result = array.
        filter(a => a.time === '09:00').
        map(({ level, type }) => ({ level, type })).
        reduce((r, o, i) => (Object.keys(o).forEach(k => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(o[k])), r), {});
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've upvoted you but seems like this is no the right solution ;d

Comment: @Kinduser, actually, the requested result of OP is invalid.

Comment: Actually his desired solution is clear, but anyways once again I've learned something new from you.

Comment: @Nina, probably you were the one downvoted. I should explain here again, that JSON was figurative.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tmp = [{time: '09:00', 'level':'x3', 'type':'ae'},
  {time: '10:00', 'level':'x6', 'type':'fe'},
  {time: '09:00', 'level':'y3', 'type':'hy'},
  {time: '11:00', 'level':'z3', 'type':'hy'}];

var result = {}; result.levels = []; result.types = [];

tmp.filter(data => data.time === '09:00').map(data => {
  result.levels.push(data.level);
  result.types.push(data.type);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I always advocate for **ONLY** using `reduce` when more than one array method is being chained together

```
const tmp = [
    {time: '09:00', 'level':'x3', 'type':'ae'},
    {time: '10:00', 'level':'x6', 'type':'fe'},
    {time: '09:00', 'level':'y3', 'type':'hy'},
    {time: '11:00', 'level':'z3', 'type':'hy'}
]

const result = tmp.reduce((acc, { time, level, type }) => {
    if (time === '09:00') {
        acc.levels.push(level)
        acc.types.push(type)
    }
    return acc
}, { levels: [], types: [] })
```

this cuts down on iterations and gives the same result